# Ошибка метода setOnItemClickListener при входе в раздел с drawer

Tags: java, android-fragment, android-drawer

Что-то не так в фрагементе?

```
public class BikeFragment extends ListFragment {
    public final static String TAG = "Bike";
    private BikeShop bikeShop = new BikeShop();

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        List<HashMap<String, String>> listBikeShop = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < bikeShop.getListShops().size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();

            hm.put("img", Integer.toString(bikeShop.getIconShops().get(i)));
            hm.put("txt", bikeShop.getListShops().get(i));
            listBikeShop.add(hm);
        }

        String[] from = {"img", "txt"};
        int[] to = {R.id.imgForList, R.id.textForList};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), listBikeShop, R.layout.list_single, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_bike_2);

        ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.travelList);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(bikeShop.getLinkShop(position)));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> Exeption: BikeFragment.java:47 -> listView.setOnItemClickListener
>
> ```
> 07-24 20:39:52.966  20170-20170/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at com.hrom.andrew.travelshops.Fragments.BikeFragment.onViewCreated(BikeFragment.java:47)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
>         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
>         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

Comment: Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Все, разобрался... Нужно переопределить метод onListItemClick с класу ListFragment, родной метод

```
@Override public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) { super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id); Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(bikeShop.getLinkShop(position))); startActivity(intent); }
```